# How to solve reccurence relation with ceiling

Tags: recurrence-relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have no clue how to solve a recurrence relation which contains ceiling function

How can I solve this:

***Equation:*** $a_n=0.2*\lceil a_{n-1} \rceil$ with $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 20$ 
?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note there is no general method to deal with recurrence relations involving the ceiling function. It depends on things like how the ceiling function is being used, what the initial value is, etc. To handle them, I suggest you calculate a few values to see if there's any pattern you can determine, and then try to prove it.

For example, consider the equation you gave of

$$a_n=0.2*\lceil a_{n-1} \rceil \tag{1}\label{1}$$

You didn't specify an initial value, so I will show the behavior of various ranges. First, if $-1 \lt a_0 \le 0$, then $a_1 = 0.2 \times \lceil a_0 \rceil = 0.2 \times 0 = 0$. Thus, you get $0 = a_2 = a_3 = \ldots$, i.e., $a_n = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$. Note having $a_1 = 20$ is not consistent with using $a_0 = 0$ and the recurrence relation for the rest of the values. However, if you do start from $a_1 = 20$ instead, then you get $a_2 = 4$, $a_3 = 0.8$, then $0.2 = a_4 = a_5 = \ldots$, i.e., $a_n = 0.2$ for $n \ge 4$.

Next, if $0 \lt a_0 \le 1$, then you have $a_1 = 0.2 \times \lceil a_0 \rceil = 0.2 \times 1 = 0.2$. However, then $a_3 = 0.2$ as well and, in fact, $a_n = 0.2$ for all $n \ge 1$.

However, if $1 \lt a_0 \le 2$, then $a_1 = 0.2 \times \lceil a_0 \rceil = 0.2 \times 2 = 0.4$. Once again, you then get $0.2 = a_2 = a_3 \ldots$, so $a_n = 0.2$ for all $n \ge 2$.

In fact, for any positive $a_0$, you'll eventually get all later values of $a_n$ to be $0.2$, and for any $a_0$ being non-positive, you'll eventually get all later values to be $0$.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention a0 = 0 and a1 = 20

Comment: @user2426691 Those values are not consistent with your recurrence relation. If $a_0 = 0$, then $a_1 = 0.2 \times \lceil 0 \rceil = 0.2 \times 0 = 0$. Instead, I suggest you just select an initial value for $a_0$ and have the rest of the values then come from the recurrence relation, as I've indicated in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! But what is the characteristic equation then?

Comment: I thought you needed to find characteristic equation to solve a recurrence relation

Comment: @user2426691 You're welcome. The "characteristic equation", e.g., as described at [Solving Linear Recurrence Relations](http://nms.lu.lv/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/21-linear-recurrences.pdf), is for linear recurrence relations. *However*, with the ceiling function on any of the definitions of the terms, like you're asking about & as in your example recurrence, it's no longer *linear*. Thus, in general, there's no such thing as a characteristic equation which applies. A linear recurrence relation example is $a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1} - 3a_{n}$, i.e., each term is only changed by constant multiplies.

Comment: So in this case, I use your answer, correct?

Comment: @user2426691 For your specific recurrence relation, you can use the answer I've provided. In general, though, if you have a recurrence relation involving a ceiling function (or any other such non-linear behavior), I suggest you do as I've indicated, i.e., calculate a few values to see if there's any pattern you can see, and then try to prove it.

Comment: Thank you my friend!!! Really appreciate it

Comment: Sorry to annoy you again John, but what do I try to prove exactly? And I'll be using proof by induction, correct?

Comment: @user2426691 In your specific case, it's relatively simple and obvious to see & confirm how $a_n$ behaves for larger values of $n$. In general, though, it won't be quite that simple. You may notice a pattern of some sort, e.g., $a_n = 2 + 3^n$, which appears to work. As you stated, you would usually use a proof by induction in those cases. However, keep in mind these are only generalities, with possibly another proof technique being simpler or more appropriate to use in specific cases. With math, there's usually no absolute methodologies, which is partially what makes it so hard & interesting.